# how fixed "text hint" in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design

I need to use "errorValidation" and "hint" in TextInputLayout.
I want to fixed hint in TextInputLayout that it does not go to the label of my TextInputLayout.
Actually, I want the hint to be as a label at first.

in other words:
I use the hint as TextView for the label of TextInputLayout but the problem is too much margin !!!
how can I handle this?

the attached picture define how I use TextView for the label of TextInputLayout.

[image]

the code I used:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_previous_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_change_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_5x"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_3x"
    android:text="@string/label_previous_password"
    style="@style/TextHintYekanRegularHintColor16" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_previous_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_label_previous_password"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_3x"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_3x"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_previous_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextYekanRegularColorPurpleOne16"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve margin problem of TextInputLayout with two tricks. You have used one trick that use a normal EditText instead of hint. Then you must set

```
app:hintEnabled="false"
```

to remove the margin on top of your TextInputLayout.

Second trick is that you should enable error for TextInputLayout in your fragment or activity instead of the layout file. This will remove the margin in the bottom of TextInputLayout. And when error is gone you should disable error for TextInputLayout. This code will do the trick for you:

```
your_text_input_layout.isErrorEnabled = true // to enable the error
your_text_input_layout.isErrorEnabled = false // to disable the error
```